# Map-Reduce: Writing multiple files per mapper

Tags: mapreduce

I have a long running map only job. Each mapper processes around 25G data and writes one files . Input data is sorted so I can't split input data to multiple mappers. However output data doesn't need to be sorted. How can I write multiple files per mapper so that output files are not that big ? I want to close currently open file whenever that file is big enough (say 1G) and start writing to different file.

Comment: Why don't you take advantage of framework...Define split size if you just want to split file in to small chunk

Comment: What configuration setting do I need for that?

Comment: How is it indexed...If you want to preserve Index then i have explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835954/hadoop-sort-the-key-and-change-the-key-value/17850370#17850370